# Functions Removed from Julia 1.0.0

Tags: julia

According to the August 2018 Julia [blogpost](https://julialang.org/blog/2018/08/one-point-zero)

> The language itself is significantly leaner, with many components split out into “standard library” packages that ship with Julia but aren’t part of the “base” language.

Is there a link to what was removed from the "base" language for the 1.0.0 version and the appropriate packages to use those items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can inspect all standard libraries in the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/). Check the navigation on the left side for the section "Standard Library".

Note that there are also [efforts](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28712) to improve the documentation of the stdlibs.

Regarding the pre v0.7 -> v1.0 transition, to my knowledge there is no all-encompassing document that tells you where functionality has been moved. However, there are fairly comprehensive sources like

- [Julia v0.7 release notes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.7/NEWS.md)
- [Julia v0.7 itself](https://julialang.org/downloads/) (run your old colde in it and you'll get very helpful deprecation warnings)
- Julia v0.7's [base/deprecations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.7/base/deprecated.jl) (basically the same as above in non-executable form)

And last but not least, there is stackoverflow and [discourse](http://discourse.julialang.org) where you can simply ask (after checking above sources yourself)!

Comment: There's also a JuliaLang Slack channel, which is more informal and conversational.